# scalebox / resizebox shifts fraction component

Tags: scaling, fractions

I have the following code in my document:

```
$$ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)}
        {\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)} $$
```

resulting in:
                                                [image]
I prefer "display style" here, but the size of the contents in the numerator and denominator are a bit too large for my liking in the context where they appear, so I decided to scale down.

```
$$ \frac{\scalebox{0.75}{\text{$\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)$}}}
        {\scalebox{0.75}{\text{$\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)$}}} $$
```

but for some reason, this causes an unwanted shift:

[image]

so I'm forced to go back to standard "text style" mode in the meantime...

I can't spot why this might be happening based on the code above; I've also tried `resizebox` but it has the same issue ... has anyone got any idea why it's happening or how I could fix it?

(**EDIT:** I solved my particular problem by scaling down the fraction as a whole rather than its constituent parts; but the question remains. Is this a latex bug? Thanks.)

Comment: You probably want `\frac{\sum\limits_i \min(A_i,B_i)}{\sum\limits_i \max(A_i,B_i)}`.

Comment: Also, avoid `$$....$$`

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: fair enough, thanks for the link; `\[ ... \]` is irrelevant here though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you don't really want `\displaystyle`, but neither you want `\scalebox`.

The size of `\min` and the other letters is right, it's just the summation symbol that grow too large:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\sum\limits_i \min(A_i,B_i)}
     {\sum\limits_i \max(A_i,B_i)}
\qquad
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)}
     {\displaystyle\sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to go the `\scalebox` way, enclose them in `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\mbox{\scalebox{0.75}{$\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)$}}}
     {\mbox{\scalebox{0.75}{$\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)$}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

The issue is apparently due to how TeX typesets fractions, putting aside the numerator until it decides the size; the assignments performed by `\scalebox` get wrong without this further level of boxing.

Or, maybe better, use `\mfrac` from the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\mfrac{\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)}
      {\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)}
\qquad
\frac{\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)}
      {\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All excellent suggestions, and good explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

can you try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\long\def\Gscale@box#1[#2]#3{%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox\bgroup%<<<<<<<<
  \def\Gscale@x{#1}\def\Gscale@y{#2}%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{{#3}}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\Gscale@start\rlap{\copy\z@}\Gscale@end}%
  \ifdim#2\p@<\z@
    \ht\tw@-#2\dp\z@
    \dp\tw@-#2\ht\z@
  \else
    \ht\tw@#2\ht\z@
    \dp\tw@#2\dp\z@
  \fi
  \ifdim#1\p@<\z@
    \hb@xt@-#1\wd\z@{\kern-#1\wd\z@\box\tw@\hss}%
  \else
    \wd\tw@#1\wd\z@
    \box\tw@
  \fi
  \egroup%<<<<<<<<
}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\scalebox{0.75}{$\displaystyle \sum_i \min(A_i,B_i)$}}
     {\scalebox{0.75}{$\displaystyle \sum_i \max(A_i,B_i)$}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This indeed fixes the odd behaviour, though I will admit it's a bit beyond my TeX skills so I don't quite follow it :) I decided to accept egreg's answer instead since that addresses my problem a bit more intuitively, but thank you for this answer!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32124111#32124111  :-)

Comment: ahahahah. I'm sorry I'm sorry I'm sorry xD

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I'll add the above fix to graphics at the next release, so then the extra box in the document as in egreg's version won't be needed (but won't do any harm)

Comment: Glad to hear it! For the record, I don't know if this makes you more or less grumpy, hahah, but I used neither solution since I already 'solved' my problem as described in my edited question :p  Glad to hear my question ended up being of some use though!